# description in mathematics

Tags: limits, continued-fractions, euler-mascheroni-constant

I have a general question. I would like to describe the different ways of representing euler's number. My question is how to describe something in mathematics. 
The Euler number can be represented either as the limit value, continued fraction and taylor series. If I enumerate the advantages and disadvantages of the representation types, is that a part of describing?
I want the meaning of describing something in maths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mathematics a formal unambiguous description of a number (or of any other mathematical object) is called a **definition**.

As your example of Euler's number shows, a mathematical object can have several different definitions. If we can show that each definition implies and is implied by each of the other definitions, then the definitions are **equivalent**. A set of equivalent definitions gives us different points of view of an object. There is not necessarily any single "best" definition - some definitions may be clearer for teaching purposes, others may be more suited to addressing particular types of problems. Choosing to use one definition rather than another depends on what your goals are.

Comment: Super answer :)